# How to save the http session in qt application

Tags: php, qt, session, qtnetwork

Now I have a web server written with php. And there some php script files for database accessing. I'm writing a Qt app to send get/post request to the remote php scripts. However, it's not convenient to verify user identity for each request. So, I want to use session control on the web server. But I don't know how to do in Qt application.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_http_cookies_with_Qt) will help you get cookie support in your app and then you can use sessions as you would in a web browser.

Comment: PHP handles session identity using token that token is either kept in cookies or is passed in url. So all you need is to pass token returned by WS when service started. Let's see your http request part of qt application so we can see how you handle requests and answers will be more helpful.

Comment: @Orangepill thanks so much, your comment helps me, cookie is the right way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Orangepill and PLB said, the solution is `Passing cookies to the request url`, you may refer to `QNetworkAccessManager::setCookieJar`.

### Steps

1. Instantiate the `QNetworkAccessManager` object and call `setCookieJar` for it.
2. Send POST request to the authenticate page which activates a session. Then you will have cookies got from the page in the `cookieJar`.
3. Send requests to the pages under the domain will with the session alive.