# Handling multiple clients from QT web server

Tags: javascript, c++, qt

I have built an application in c++ QT which has an in built web server running on the embedded platform. On hitting the ip address of the device, the http server gives out a static file to the client to login to system and predefined  users can login.

Even the http server is taken care to handle multiple clients and each has it's own thread to provide the static file which in turn loads the html content.

This Webcontent has multiple files to navigate and each html is dynamic loading based on the selection of a dropdown and the data is given from the c++ application, for this I have used web sockets and Qwebchannel methodologies.

Now the issue that is faced is,the user opens multiple session and navigates to a webpage having dynamic content in both. Now in one of the session the user selects the dropdown as "India" for which the data specific to India is retrieved from the DB which C++ is handling and is shown on the page. In other session the user selects "France", this session gets the data specific to France, but the older session which has the data specific to India is updated to France.

In short, whenever backend c++ gets a request from any of the client, it responds to all the clients connected. The request is a Q_INVOKABLE function that is exposed to JS and the reply is a signal to JS with the data in QJson format.

Searched for this extensively in the internet but was unable to find a solution. Is there any way that Q_INVOKABLE function in C++ can know which client is requesting and respond to only that client ?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to write the program you described so without seeing any code it is hard to give you a concrete answer here so I try to explain the theory behind it.

Simply put, your server needs a global data structure like a map or a dictionary or even using the file system to keep track of more than one “session” or client all at the same time.

What you want is commonly known as “session management”. To make it easy you can think of HTTP as a “connection oriented network protocol” at the “application level” meaning the two systems talking to each other (the client and the server) do already have a unique token accessible to applications distinguishing the particular client if you are using the HTTP protocol in your code.

What you need to do is to create or somehow findout this unique token in your C++ access point when a request arrives and then create new data records for every new token (new session) or access an existing data record if the token is a subsequent client request that was already being served. To improve performance then you can store this unique token in a “thread-local memory” in each of those threads so the threads know which “session” they are serving.

This is usually the job of a “session manager” and Qt does provides some primitives to help you create a session manager with distinguished requests and replies. Have a look at these posts and links for instance:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html

[How to save the http session in qt application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669978/how-to-save-the-http-session-in-qt-application)

Keep in mind that if you are using a “connection-less” protocol for performance or whatever other reasons then you have to invent your own ways to distinguish between sessions - for example the client always sending a unique ID in each and every request or using the client’s IP address together with its system process ID to create that unique ID.

Now in practice HTTP and its reliance on the lower level TCP makes the whole argument a little more complex. Have a look at this post for example:
https://serverfault.com/questions/428924/http-tcp-udp-and-connectionless

The phrases I used above “connection oriented” or “connection less” really refer to protocols below the application level. So to say HTTP is connection oriented is not entirely correct. It is the TCP protocol on which HTTP usually relies on that is connection oriented. The phrase “connection” at the TCP level is a bit similar to the physical connection. If you lose that and then connect to the same client again it doesn’t always mean you lose your “session” between the two applications. And the phrase “session” may refer to a session between two TCP parties or it may refer to that unique token established between two applications (the client and the server). So try to not confuse the terms when reading the literature.

But you get the idea.

I hope this helps.